# SilverStripe Sapphire Functional testing on POST request is always returning 404 status

Tags: unit-testing, silverstripe, functional-testing, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. I am trying to write functional tests for my application following this documentation, https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/testing/functional_testing/. I am testing a POST request. But it is not working. You can see my code below.

I have a controller class called CustomFormPageController with the following code.

```
class CustomFormPageController extends PageController
{
    private static $allowed_actions = [
        'testPostRequest',
    ];

    private static $url_handlers = [
        'testPostRequest' => 'testPostRequest',
    ];

    public function testPostRequest(HTTPRequest $request)
    {
        if (! $request->isPOST()) {
            return "Bad request";
        }

        return "Request successfully processed";
    }
}
```

I also have a page class for that controller called, CustomFormPage. Following is the implementation of the class.

```
class CustomFormPage extends Page
{

}
```

What I am trying to test is that I am trying to test testPostRequest method returns the correct value.

Following is my test class

```
class CustomFormPageTest extends FunctionalTest
{
    protected static $fixture_file = 'fixtures.yml';

    public function testTestingPost()
    {
        $formPage = $this->objFromFixture(CustomFormPage::class, 'form_page');

        $response = $this->post($formPage->URLSegment . '/testPostRequest', [
            'name' => 'testing'
        ]);

        var_dump($response);
    }
}
```

Following is my fixtures.yml file.

```
SilverStripe\CMS\Model\SiteTree:
    sitetree_page_one:
        ID: 1
        ClassName: CustomFormPage
        Title: Page Title 1
        URLSegment: custom-form-page
CustomFormPage:
    form_page:
        ID: 1
        Title: Page Title 1
        URLSegment: custom-form-page
```

When I run the test, it is always returning 404 not found status even though the page is created in the database. What is missing in my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. We need to publish the page in the test as follows.

```
$formPage->publish("Stage", "Live");
```

Comment: You can also use `protected static $use_draft_site = true` to use draft instead of live